# How do I list files in web folder of a different java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I need to list files under a folder of a different web application. Is there a way to get this done without having to provide the actual path in a properties file?

```
Webapps
 - WebApp1
    -MyFolderOfInterest
 - WebApp2 
   - WEB-INF
     - Classes
       - MyClasstoListFiles
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in a servlet of yours:

```
getServletContext().getContext("/WebApp1").getResource("/MyFolderOfInterest")
```

The important things here is that you gain access to a `ServletContext` different than the one you are currently in. See the documentation of [`getContext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29)

And in order to make a context eligible for access from other contexts, for WebApp2 you need a `context.xml` (in `META-INF`, for example) that contains:

```
<Context crossContext="true" ... />
```

Comment: I am guessing you meant getServletContext().getContext("/WebApp1").getResource("/MyFolderOfInterest") 
However, it looks like getResource returns an URL and not a file object that is needed for directory listing etc...

Comment: did you make the context be `crossContext=true` ?